# Unable to login as admin with Postfix in docker container

Tags: postfix, docker-compose

I have tried to setup Postfix as a test server to allow TDD-tests to run with email verification on a local email server.
This is my yml file for docker compose

```yml
  postfixadmin:
    image: postfixadmin
    ports:
      - 9000:80
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTFIXADMIN_DB_TYPE: sqlite
      POSTFIXADMIN_DB_HOST: 192.168.0.12
      POSTFIXADMIN_DB_PORT:
      POSTFIXADMIN_DB_USER: postfixadmin
      POSTFIXADMIN_DB_NAME: /var/tmp/postfixadmin.db
      POSTFIXADMIN_DB_PASSWORD: example
      POSTFIXADMIN_SETUP_PASSWORD: $$2y$$10$$LvtzgPciAKYK9UH3hKwekOki9/RXeV512BsJFxXD8GSME.vQO9Aq2
```

The POSTFIXADMIN_SETUP_PASSWORD was retrieved by running http://localhost:9000/setup.php
In this example it was chosen to be example123.
However I am unable to login with this setup password. I have to restart the container, maybe it's differently salted each time?
I don't know I just can't login on anything but the server is running in the container.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong or do I have to switch to some other software instead?

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Is this your complete docker compose because you are missing a few things?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution so leaving it for others as some kind of reference.

I had to enter double-$ to escape the variable lookup

Answer (score 0):

for those who couldn't get the hash to be added to the file correctly i used the `tee` command after getting my hash like this:

```
php -r 'echo password_hash("password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);'
```

change "password" with your new password then take the result and add `\` before each `$`

> if you got: `$2y$10$xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

> then you type it like: `$2y\$10\$xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

then run this:

```
echo "<?php
                \$CONF['database_type'] = 'mysqli';
                \$CONF['database_host'] = '--------------------';
                \$CONF['database_port'] = '3306';
                \$CONF['database_user'] = '--------------------';
                \$CONF['database_password'] = '--------------------';
                \$CONF['database_name'] = '--------------------';
                \$CONF['setup_password'] = '\$2y\$10\$xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
                \$CONF['smtp_server'] = 'localhost';
                \$CONF['smtp_port'] = '25';
                \$CONF['encrypt'] = 'md5crypt';
                \$CONF['configured'] = true;
                \$CONF['dkim'] = 'NO';
                \$CONF['dkim_all_admins'] = 'NO';
                ?>" | tee config.local.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `network_mode: host` Using the host network allows the container to directly access services running on the host